# В vscode не работает intelligence

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Переустановил винду. Открываю проект на vscode 1.41.1. intelligence работает где-то 15 секунд потом вырубается. Расширений нет. Все настройки дефолтные. Откатился на 1.40.2 потом поставил insiders версию (1.42.0) - такая же проблема.
Подсказки не появляются при простом вводе. При нажатии на ctrl+space тоже не работает. ЦП начинает грузить.
Проверял в разных проектах. Почему-то именно в проектах созданных с помощью create-react-app не пашет.
В старом ОС все работало нормально. Как можно попробовать исправить проблему и из-за она возникает?
Спасибо!

Comment: Наверное не _intelligence_, а _IntelliSence_?.. и/или не _IntelliSence_, а _**code completion**_ в целом?

Comment: оперативы сколько?

Comment: аналогичная ситуация с VSCode, нормально не отображаются подсказки при вводе, работал с `Vue` и не было ничего что мне нужно было. Озу 16 Gb, последних версий VScode, расширения не ставил, всё дефолтное.

Comment: @ARSLN, ДА! ts или flow

Comment: @MoloF, https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Editor-Support

Comment: @yar85 Да, IntelliSense. Я думал IntelliSense это и есть code completion? Короче не работает автодополнение)

Comment: @qwabra 12gb, i5 4210, gtx 850m, w10 ltsb

Comment: @ARSLN, А что в консолях выводится? (в "Вывод → Расширения", и в той что в devtools электрона)

Comment: @yar85 Не нашел "Вывод → Расширения" =( А в консоле devtools электрона пусто